# .Net Framework Initialization Error – Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application (TypeInitializationException)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, deployment, .net-4.0

I'm experiencing the err above with my app as I attempt to deploy it, but only in certain scenarios:

1. In the VS IDE: no problem, my app runs fine
2. Double-clicking my .exe in Windows explorer: no problem, my app runs fine
3. Right-clicking my .exe in Windows explorer and selecting "Run As": I get the error above, and it won't run
4. Right-clicking my .exe in Windows explorer on a remote machine where the .exe has been deployed and selecting "Run As": I get the error above, and it won't run
5. Double-clicking a desktop link/shortcut to the .exe on a remote machine where the .exe has been deployed: very vague err msg, and my app won't run.

The info from the Windows Event Log (after failure with scenario 3) is:

```
Type: Error
Source: .NET Runtime
Message: Application: duckbilledPlatypus.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:   at duckbilledPlatypus.duckbilledPlatypusMainForm..ctor()
   at duckbilledPlatypus.Program.Main()
```

I'm flailing about, searching and trying different things, grasping at straws. Here's one:

Is there something wrong with the layout of my App.config file (below)?

Note: I just added "supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" but it made no difference; do I need to add "startup" to the "configSections" section?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"     
type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,     
log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender"     
type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ISO8601} [%thread]     
%-5level %-50.50logger | %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="DebugAppender"     
type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
      <immediateFlush value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout"/>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"    
sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Note: I have the following .NET versions installed: 1.0.3705; 1.1.4322; 2.0.50727; 3.0; 3.5; and 4.0.30319

So does the user on whose machine I've deployed my app...

If I change the startup to:

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" 
sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0.30319" />
  </startup>
```

I get (even in the IDE), "*To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework: .NETFramework,Version=4.0.30319
Would you like to download and install .NETFramework,Version-v4.0.30319 now?*"

If I just use this, though:

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
  </startup>
```

It runs in the IDE fine...but I still have all the problematic other scenarios (chiefly, that it won't run in the deployed location)...???

### UPDATE

In answer to Charleh, the only thing in the main form's constructor is:

```
InitializeComponent();

foreach (string arg in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()) {
    if (arg == "-DEBUG") {
        InDebugMode = true;
        break;
    }
}

tsch = new ToolStripControlHost(dateTimePickerDuckbilledPlatypus);
toolStripDuckbilledPlatypusMain.Items.Add(tsch);
```

### UPDATED AGAIN

I just tried removing the following from App.config altogether:

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
  </startup>
```

...but it makes no difference.

### UPDATED YET AGAIN

It seemed that once I copied over a file that it needed to access (a .txt file), it ran fine (it did so once). But now it's back to not even wanting to open again, and the event log data is:

```
Source: .NET Runtime
Message: Application: duckbilledPlatypus.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException
Stack:   at duckbilledPlatypus.duckbilledPlatypusMainForm.InitializeComponent()
   at duckbilledPlatypus.duckbilledPlatypusMainForm..ctor() at duckbilledPlatypus.Program.Main()
```

Will this problem arise if more than one people are accessing either the .exe or the .txt?

### UPDATED FOR THE FINAL TIME, I RECKON

The upshot is, first I had failed to copy a couple of .dlls and a text file that the .exe needed. Once those were there, it ran fine. STILL, THOUGH, it seems quite bizarre to me that right-clicking the file gave the bogus err msg about a missing/wrong version of the .NET runtime AND that the err msg is so misleading. Why can't an err msg tell you which .DLL or file that was not found? That would make debugging so much simpler/faster.

Comment: Just a thought but possibly you have a missing reference and something is trying to access an object that belongs to that assembly in the main form constructor - what's in the main form constructor?

Comment: Oh and additionally, there are 2 versions of .net 4 - the client profile and the full profile. One has certain components missing

Comment: Stupid question, maybe, but you never know: any permission settings on the .config file itself?

Comment: @Charleh - appended the answer to my original post.

Comment: I'd recommend adding a handler to AppDomain.UnhandledException, then write to the event log. Write the full stack trace or exception trace to the log e.g. create a function to look at Exception.InnerException recursively and then append to a StringBuilder - write that to the log - then at least you will see the exception. At the moment you are only seeing the top of the stack trace. The clue is pretty much the TypeInitializationException though, sounds like a missing assembly

Comment: @Charleh: At first it was targeting .NET 4 Client Profile (I don't know why that's apparently the default setting...?), but I changed it to "regular" .NET 4 - no difference.

Comment: Try the above see if that works - ideally your app should be catching all exceptions, but second best is to grab any unhandled exceptions in the current AppDomain and log accordingly. The app will still exit, but at least you get the full story

Comment: @David: The config file is not readonly, and it has full security for everybody (administrators, system, myself). However, the only file that's been deployed is the *.exe file - am I missing something? I'm assuming that everything that is needed is compiled into the .exe... other than the log4net .dll and our custom framework .dll

Comment: Everything should be compiled into the `.exe`, yes.  Since the problem happens when you run as a different user, my guess would be that you have some code that relies on relative file paths or some other condition that is non-consistent when running as a different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error description you posted above, I think this is not related to the .NET framework at all; rather, this looks to be that your form's constructor is throwing an error.  This is backed up by the fact that the stack trace starts at `duckbilledPlatypus.duckbilledPlatypusMainForm..ctor()`.

Try commenting out code in your constructor and seeing if the application runs.  If it does run, you can investigate more closely on which code is causing the unhandled exception.  My suspicion is that you could have a control on your form when `InitializeComponent` is run that is causing this exception.

Comment: There is a login form that is automatically invoked by our custom framework .dll that may be the culprit...

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a forms app, add this and see if you get more info from the error; you may need to register the event log source using EventLog.CreateEventSource()

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.Automatic);
        Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
    }

    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        EventLog eLog = new EventLog("SomeLog", ".", "YourApp");

        eLog.WriteEntry(UnrollException(e.Exception), EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }

    static string UnrollException(Exception ex)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(ex.Message);

        while (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            ex = ex.InnerException;
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(ex.Message);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Edit: Disclaimer - I've not actually run this code, so it might throw some exceptions of it's own :D